# how to return a reference of a vector element from a function operator(x,y)

Tags: c++, vector, reference, operator-keyword

I have a class template which contains a vector of T as a protected member variable. I want to overload the operator() so that it returns a reference of the vector's element in line y and column x.

When i declare the operator() function as:

```
template <class T>
T & ArrayT<T>::operator()(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)const{
    return buffer[y*width + x];
}
```

i get C2440 error: 'return': cannot convert from 'const_Ty' to 'T&'

If i declare the operator function as:

```
template <class T>
const T & ArrayT<T>::operator()(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)const{
    return buffer[y*width + x];
}
```

then my code compiles but if for example i create a derived templeted class where T is float and i write (obj is an object of the derived class with a member variable vector of floats):

```
float f=obj(i,j); 
f=pow(f,2);
```

then nothing seems to happen. The float in the position i,j inside the vector does not change so assume that i dont really work on a reference, because if a reference was returned by the operator () the above lines should change the element in position (i,j) right?

I am new to c++ and i understand i might be doing some very silly mistakes here, but please any kind of help woulb be welcome.

Comment: You should remove the 2 `const` in your operator declaration and use `float & f = obj(i,j);`. But note that your design approach is not good. Consider using a setter function to modify elements of the protected vector.

Comment: i have consider making a setter function and i have trying removing const from the operator declaration. My problem is that the object which uses the operator will be const so the setter function does not apply in that case and removing const from the operator declaration makes the operator unapplicable in case of a const object. Is there any other approach i can try?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense modifying a const object, does it?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the operator without `const`, like this:

```
template <class T>
T & ArrayT<T>::operator()(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    return buffer[y*width + x];
}
```

Access elements like this:

```
float & f = obj(i, j);
```

---

We usually provide const operator (as OP did):

```
template <class T>
const T & ArrayT<T>::operator()(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const {
    return buffer[y*width + x];
}

float f = obj(i, j);          // f is copy of current i,j value 

const float & f = obj(i, j);  // f references i,j value, i.e. we can
                              // observe future modifications
```

Comment: Usually, we implement both versions, const and non const.